# Calling a function during jquery tabs hide

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

For jqueryUI's tabs, I'm familiar w/ adding a function to the show event, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228278/jquery-ui-tabs-show-all-tab).  However, is there a way to add a function when a tab is unloaded or loses focus?  I see there is a hide function, but my function doesn't get called when I click away from a tab (to another tab).

Here is my code:

```
$("#myTabs").tabs({ 
    selected: tab, 
    show: 
        function (event, ui) { 
            //some code that works
        },
    hide:
        function(event, ui) {
            //some code that never gets called
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to accomplish something during the hide function, I added a custom function in my "select".  You can read more about it on this other question.

[Jquery Tabs showing a confirmation before activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959814/jquery-tabs-showing-a-confirmation-before-activate)