# Jquery modal dialog that stops in-page action

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have reviewed lots of pages about jquery modal dialogs, but still have not found something that works how I need it to.

If a user makes a change and clicks an internal link on our site, I want a dialog to pop up with 3 button options -- Save, Discard, and Cancel.  If they click save, it will call the save function, then leave the page.

But the page is set up with tabs, with each tab loading a different php page into a master page.  The links are not hard links, and they do not reload the page.  They are like in-page anchor links (that then load a php page).  So I cannot capture the anchor request and send it to the address bar later.

I already have the dialog, set as modal.  But right now, when I click another tab, it loads the tab, and pops up my dialog at the same time.  I want it to not load the tab until a button is clicked in the dialog.

The confirm() function does this perfectly.  But my modal dialog allows the other tab to load.  Can you help me set up a modal dialog that works like the confirm function in this instance?

Here is my Javascript function:

```
        function fw_chkTabStatusFmla() {
        if (jsg_fwTabWatchFmla == false) {

           $(function() {
              $( "#tabWarnFmla" ).dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height:240,
                  width:400,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Discard": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                           //discard changes and continue
                    },
                    "Save": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                           //function to save changes and continue
                    },
                  }
              });
          });
      }
 }
```

This is the old one I was using.  It stops the behavior correctly, but only allows for two buttons.

```
        function fw_chkTabStatusFmla() {
        if (jsg_fwTabWatchFmla == false) {
            var x = confirm("If you leave this tab without saving you may lose your changes.\n\nClick 'OK' to proceed without saving.");
            if (x == true)         {
                jsg_fwTabWatchFmla = true;
                setConfirmUnload(false);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am setting the jsg_fwTabWatchFmla variable to false when changes are made in the pertinent fields.

Here is what I have to run the function.

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs({
            select: function(event, ui) {                    
                return fw_chkTabStatusFmla();
            }
            });
    }
```

Comment: where is your code? Read the FAQ!

Comment: add some code so we can provide an answer

Comment: I apologize.  I was unsure of how to post my link code in a way that makes sense.  I have just added the javascript code.

Comment: You can't block page actions with a jQuery dialog. Only vanilla JS prompts, alerts, and confirms can do that.

Comment: Could I use a workaround of some kind?  I'm ok with using a delay timer that automatically selects a certain action after X seconds, if something like that will stop the page action.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to change the action of your tabs.  I'm not sure what Tabs plugin you're using.  But with jQuery UI Tabs I'd use this method:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

beforeActivate( event, ui )Type: tabsbeforeactivate

Triggered directly after a tab is activated. Can be canceled to prevent the tab from activating. If the tabs are currently collapsed, ui.oldTab and ui.oldPanel will be empty jQuery objects. If the tabs are collapsing, ui.newTab and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks - that put me on the right track.  Unfortunately, the site I'm working on does not have a new enough version of jquery/jquery ui to use the beforeActivate method.  I found a nearly identical discussion here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959814/jquery-tabs-showing-a-confirmation-before-activate
They concluded that it has to be done with a confirm, as I was doing before.  Thanks for your help!